# Remove multiple file handlers for manipulating data

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to clean up my code block so it doesn't have to use multiple file handlers.

However, I need csv in order to read lines in file by values (comma separated), but then I need the regular file functionality to replace text.

Is there anyway I can minizmize the file handler usage with this code:

```
api = Trading(config_file='ebay.yaml')

f = open("row_data.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    desktop_images_link = row[1]
    desktop_images = desktop_images_link.split('|')

    for x in desktop_images:
        files = {'file': ('EbayImage', open(x, 'rb'))}
        api.execute('UploadSiteHostedPictures', files=files)
        dictstr = api.response.dict()
        hosted_url = dictstr["SiteHostedPictureDetails"]["FullURL"]
        o = open("row_data.csv").read()
        o = o.replace(x,hosted_url)
        w = open("row_data.csv",'w')
        w.write(o)
        w.close()
```

Comment: when cleaning the code for this post I shouldn't have deleted one line defining the desktop_images list. I've added it back into code

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.

Comment: Next: Why do you need to do a full-text replacement? Does each of those strings in `desktop_images` appear in other rows? Or in unpredictable other columns of the same row? Because it you're just trying to replace them in, say, columns 3-5 of the current row, or just as substrings of column 1, then you can easily do that while still treating the file as a CSV.

Comment: In every row the second column is a pipe delimited list of URLS. The 'replace_text' is going to be unique for every record. So what it is basically doing is changing the original URL to a different URL. Then it goes row by row and does the same thing over and over again. Instead of trying to be cute, I'll add full original code to prevent any more confusion.

Comment: Are you just trying to replace the URLs in that pipe-delimited list? Or find and replace the same values in another specific column of the same row? Or find and replace the same values in any column of any row? Or…?

Comment: So for example original file has images/1.jpg|image/2.jpg. After each image goes through the api hosted_url will have the location where the file was uploaded ie., http://new1.jpg. What the script should do is replace 'images/1.jpg' with 'http://new1.jpg' and so on for each file.

Comment: But is `images/1.jpg` going to appear anywhere else in the file, or only right here, in this pipe-delimited column 1 of this row?

Comment: All paths in original file are unique. Just like all api call returns will be unique

Comment: So what made you think you needed to call `replace` on the whole file? The problem you're trying to solve basically doesn't exist; let me edit my answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to read the file as text to `replace` the image URLs. Those values don't appear anywhere else in the file but in the current column of the current row. So you don't need to call `replace` on the contents of the whole file, just on the current column of the current row.

This means you can just transform the CSV row by row.

Writing to a temporary file and then moving it over the original is better than overwriting the file in-place. That way, if you, say, trip over the power cord in the middle of a write, you either have the complete original file, or the complete new file, not half the new file and everything else is lost forever. It's also more efficient—we can have both files open at once, and never have to store more than the current row in memory. And it's simpler—no need to worry about any conflicts between two handles to the same file, because you never have two handles to the same file.

While we're at it, you don't even need `replace` here. Your column 1 is the original images piped together. You `split` them up into separate strings. You want to replace one of those strings completely with a different string. You can do that without `replace`—just use the different string instead of the original one.

So, what you want is something like this:

```
with open("row_data.csv") as fin, open("row_data.csv.tmp", "w") as fout:
    csv_in = csv.reader(fin)
    csv_out = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in csv_in:
        desktop_images_link = row[1]
        desktop_images = desktop_images_link.split('|')
        replacement_images = [hosted_url for desktop_image in desktop_images]
        row[1] = '|'.join(replacement_images)
        csv_out.writerow(row)
os.replace('row_data.csv.tmp', 'row_data.csv')
```

That's it.

---

If you really *did* need to globally replace the images, because they could appear arbitrarily in other columns of other rows anywhere in the file, you could still improve your code—making it simpler, and also fixing a serious problem with it.

The problem is that, in the middle of a loop over the rows in `row_data.csv`, you `open("row_data.csv", "w")` and overwrite the whole file. You can't do that. What you have to do is one of:

- Use a temporary file (as above) that you keep reading and writing, and then move it over the original file after you're done looping.
- Read all the rows into memory, and then do the loop.
- Read the file contents into memory, then loop over the rows and do all the `replace`s in the loop, then write it out until the end.
- Build up a list of replacements as you loop over the file, and then apply them all at the end.

The last one is probably the simplest, and (except for the first) the most efficient.

While we're at it, you should be using `with` statements to make sure all of your file objects get closed.

So:

```
all_desktop_images = []
with open("row_data.csv") as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_f:
        desktop_images_link = row[1]
        desktop_images = desktop_images_link.split('|')
        all_desktop_images.extend(desktop_images)

with open("row_data.csv") as f:
    data = f.read()
for desktop_image in all_desktop_images:
    data = data.replace(desktop_image, hosted_url)
with open("row_data.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

We still have the same number of calls to `open` in the source code, but now each one of them only executes once, instead of opening and reopening (and overwriting) the file over and over again, and we only ever have one of them open at a time, instead of having all three open at once.